# Centering <UL> + Keeping <LI>'s Aligned

Tags: html, css

My problem:
http://i56.tinypic.com/ff3jmo.png

The bullet points aren't aligned.

All I'm going is text-align:center'ing the class in which the ul resides. Can I align the bullet points?

**EDIT**: I just want to try and clarify. I want the actual bullet points aligned. Currently the text is aligned, but not the bullet points.

- T  e   x    t

  - T  e  x  t

    - T e x t

Where as I want

- Text
- Text
- Text
- (Bullet points aligned, text centered)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering Bullets On A Centered List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347833/centering-bullets-on-a-centered-list)

Answer (score 4):

`text-align: center` isn't to be used for this purpose.  You should probably put the `<ul>` in a `<div>` and center *that* by setting it to a certain width and using `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto`.

So:

```
<div style="width: 25%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <ul>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to set a width on that div.

Comment: Didn't work :S This kept the UL to the left side. To clarify, my problem is the bullet points themselves aren't aligned, but the text is. I want the bullet points aligned. I'm sorry I can't express this very well

Comment: I find `margin:0 auto;` a bit cleaner

Comment: not sure which universe, but in mine it's margin-left and margin-right

Answer (score 1):

You asked the question twice. I answered you at [Centering Bullets On A Centered List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347833/centering-bullets-on-a-centered-list/5347910#5347910)

Give your div a class name `center`. Assuming your div width is 200px, `margin:0 auto` will center and `text-align:left` will align the text to the left while maintaining its centering due to margin auto.

```
.center{
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/8mHeh/1/

Comment: You can now use `margin: 0 auto; display: table;`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the li's to align to the left? If so, try putting all of the li's in the class "myliclass" and do this in CSS:

```
.myliclass {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the li's to align to the center. text-align:center; accomplishes this, but as you can see in the screenshot the bullet points aren't aligned which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need margin  just above the `ul` tag add a `div` and add style in it 
`text-align:left`

```
<div style="text-align:left">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```