# Centering Bullets On A Centered List

Tags: html, css, alignment

<strike>Example - http://jstn.info/html.html</strike> - link rot, example no longer available.

Notice the text is centered, but the bullet points themselves are not. How can I align the bullet points while keeping the text/list centered?

Comment: I am on the actual page, but it still produces the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering <UL> + Keeping <LI>'s Aligned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347451/centering-ul-keeping-lis-aligned)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You asked the same question at [Centering <UL> + Keeping <LI>'s Aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347451/centering-ul-keeping-lis-aligned) and i already answered you.

Give your div a class name `center`. Assuming your div width is 200px, `margin:0 auto` will center and `text-align:left` will align the text to the left while maintaining its centering due to margin auto.

```
.center{
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/8mHeh/1/

Comment: You can now use `margin: 0 auto; display: table;`.

Answer (score 137):

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6558833/507421

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: While this works, it also messes with the centering. I think `display: inline-block` on the `ul` might do a better job of centering in a way you'd expect depending on your needs.

Comment: You are super epic!

Answer (score 9):

There are a bunch of ways to solve this depending on your project's UI needs.

I've listed 3 possible solutions here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/r1j95pryn

#### Centered Bullets

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

#### Left-Aligned Bullets w/ Centered Text

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

#### Centered List w/ Left-Aligned Text

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

## Visuals

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer I've found so far and nicely shows the possibilities

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the bullets are controlled by the `ul` rather than the individual `li`s. I don't know a clean way of doing this off the top of my head; as a quick hack, try

```
ul { list-style-type: none; text-align: center; }
li::before { content: "\2022 " }
/* 0x2022 is unicode for a bullet */
```

Edit: as the user above me points out, you should be centering in the stylesheet rather than with `align`.

To clarify, what we've actually done here is hidden the automatically-generated bullets (by setting `list-style-type` to `none) and created "pseudo-bullets" in front of each li.