# Bullets center with unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Does anyone know the CSS that makes the bullet point sit at the top of a multi-line bulleted list? For some reason with the template that I am using the bullet point centers to the left instead of simply sitting next to the first word if I have more than one line of text.

Comment: Can you show your code or provide a link?

Comment: Are you sure it is bullets not background images?

Comment: As above.
The bullet point from an <li> tag should sit at the top, is it using an image?
Could you provide a working sample please?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what Logan asks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you guys until now...
Yes the bullet is looking for an image. The CSS code is:

.content-a ul li { margin: 0 0 3px 0; padding: 0 0 0 13px; background: transparent url(../images/bullet-a.png) no-repeat 0 25%; }

When I was playing around with the code it was originally set to 100% but what I found was 25% fit the bullets much better. Although it is still not exact. At 25% the bullet point still sits a couple pixels below the top line and on a single line the bullet point sits a couple pixels above the line of text.

Answer (score 54):

Set the list style position to inside the list item, see **[this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/yP6fZ/)**.

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason but `li { list-style-position: inside; }` did. Could be related to the rest of the stylesheet (I'm using a template). Sorted, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer per-se but it may give others an insight to a similar visual situation with a different set of circumstances.

I had the same issue, like so:

[image: Bullet centered in text block]

My HTML looked like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link with several lines. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, commodi!</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link with several lines. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, commodi!</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See the offending part? The `vertical-align: middle;` declaration.

There are two solutions:

## Solution 1

Remove the `vertical-align: middle;` declaration altogether.

## Solution 2

Change the value: `vertical-align: middle;` to `vertical-align: top;`.

## Result (as expected in the beginning):

[image: Bullet top aligned]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

You could do something like this:

```
(css)
li div:before
{
   background-image:url('bullet.png');
}

(html)
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            text<br />
            more text
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```