# How center unordered list with bullets?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm new to web programming and I can't figure out, how to place not only text, but also the unordered list bullets in the center? Here is code:

```
 <div style="text-align:center;">
    <h2 style="margin-top:43px;" class="text-center">Important years of life and work:</h2>
    <ul >
      <li>cat nip</li>
      <li>laser pointers</li>
      <li>lasagna</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And here is the pic, to show you what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bullets center with unordered list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550069/bullets-center-with-unordered-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```css
div{
  text-align:center;
}ul{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <h2 style="margin-top:43px;" class="text-center">Important years of life and work:</h2>
    <ul >
      <li>cat nip</li>
      <li>laser pointers</li>
      <li>lasagna</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped!)

Answer (score 0):

```css
h2{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:43px;
}
 ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
   <div style="text-align:center;">
    <h2>Important years of life and work:</h2>
    <ul >
      <li>cat nip</li>
      <li>laser pointers</li>
      <li>lasagna</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```